# Bad ExpandableListView Group View recycling

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I ran into a bad issue when I tried to create an expandable listview with lazy-loaded imageViews as group views. It turned up that each time a group is opened, all the group views are redrawn but they are given a random convertView (and not theirs), which causes pretty bad blinkings as the previous imageViews are delivered randomely to the wrong groups. You can experience this issue with the following example which consists in a very simple ExpandableListView with delayed group draw that highlights quite well this unwanted behaviour. Is there a better implementation around that preserves the item/convertView bound on group openings?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int pad = 20;
private ExpandableListView listView;
private CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<GroupItem> items = new ArrayList<GroupItem>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        GroupItem item = new GroupItem();
        item.title = "Group " + i;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            item.items.add("Child " + j);
        items.add(item);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter();
    adapter.setData(items);

    listView = new ExpandableListView(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                listView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            } else {
                listView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    setContentView(listView);
}

private static class GroupItem {
    String title;
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**
 * Adapter for our list of {@link GroupItem}s.
 */
private class CustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<GroupItem> items;

    public void setData(List<GroupItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).items.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) 
            convertView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
        tv.setPadding(pad, pad, pad, pad);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        tv.setText(item);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition).items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GroupItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return items.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final GroupItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        final TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
        tv.setPadding(pad, pad, pad, pad);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText(item.title);
            }
        }, 1000);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need two view holder one for parent and another for child element.

you can try something like this.
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ContactNameItems> mListDataHeader;
private ArrayList<String> selectedNumbers;

private HashMap<String, List<ContactPhoneItems>> mListDataChild;

private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<ContactNameItems> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<ContactPhoneItems>> listDataChild,
        ArrayList<String> listOfNumbers) {

    mContext = context;
    mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    mListDataChild = listDataChild;
    selectedNumbers = listOfNumbers;

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return mListDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public ContactNameItems getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String contactName = getGroup(groupPosition).getName();
    Bitmap contactImage = getGroup(groupPosition).getImage();

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_name_item, null);

        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();

        groupViewHolder.mContactName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

        groupViewHolder.mContactImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivContactPhoto);

        convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    } else {

        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (contactImage != null) {
        groupViewHolder.mContactImage.setImageBitmap(contactImage);

    } else {
        groupViewHolder.mContactImage
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.default_contact);
    }

    groupViewHolder.mContactName.setText(contactName);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return mListDataChild.get(mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName())
            .size();
}

@Override
public ContactPhoneItems getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mListDataChild.get(mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getName())
            .get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String numberText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getNumber();
    String typeText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getPhoneType();

    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_item, null);

        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

        childViewHolder.mPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_number);

        childViewHolder.mPhoneType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_phone_type);

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);

        convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);

    } else {

        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    childViewHolder.mPhoneNumber.setText(numberText);
    childViewHolder.mPhoneType.setText(typeText);

    ContactPhoneItems cpi = getChild(mGroupPosition, childPosition);

    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(cpi);
    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(cpi.getSelected());

    // for managing the state of the boolean
    // array according to the state of the
    // CheckBox

    childViewHolder.mCheckBox
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                String contactNumber = mListDataChild
                        .get(mListDataHeader.get(mGroupPosition).getName())
                        .get(childPosition).getNumber();

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

                    if (isChecked) {

                        selectedNumbers.add(contactNumber);

                    } else {

                        selectedNumbers.remove(contactNumber);
                    }

                    getChild(mGroupPosition, childPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

public ArrayList<String> getSelectedNumbers() {

    return selectedNumbers;
}

public final class GroupViewHolder {

    TextView mContactName;
    ImageView mContactImage;
}

public final class ChildViewHolder {

    TextView mPhoneNumber;
    TextView mPhoneType;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

        ContactPhoneItems c = (ContactPhoneItems) buttonView.getTag();
        c.setSelected(isChecked);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: I really don't think that this issue is caused by the lack of ViewHolders, which I don't need because my views are not inflated anyways. Have you run the example above?